# Beginner with C#, help explaining a code snippet

Tags: c#

First of I need to be clear on the fact that I'm new to C#. I believe in a practical approach so I've mixed my reading with practical examples. I also enjoy reading code and trying to really understand it. However this one thing keeps me puzzled.

I've checked my books and the internet but I don't really know what to search for in order to find it.

Anyway here's the code.

```
for (int t = 0; t < res.Length / 2; t++)
{
    if (res[t] != res[res.Length -t -1]) Initial = false;
}
```

`res` isn't declared as an array earlier in the code, yet it's made `res[t]` in the if statement. I read something about "indexing" elsewhere but didn't get much further so now I'm asking you for help explaining this little trick for me. Hopefully the explanation wont blow my mind to pieces.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you post the rest of the code?

Comment: "res isn't declared as an array" - what's it defined as then? That's pretty critical in understanding what that code means.

Comment: What type is `res` declared as?  That would help us explain as there are many data structures in C# that can be iterated through that aren't declared as arrays

Comment: what's the type of `res` ? You can index with [] on arrays, strings, and every type defining an indexer with `this[...]`

Comment: Looks pretty straight forward. Can you be more specific what you're confused about?

Comment: it could be a List<T>

Comment: It's a string

string res; and res = sum.ToString(); are the only other places it's mentioned.

It's the solution to a project euler problem, I researched these few lines but don't want to settle with "it works" I want to understand it was well.

Comment: You could use "Go to definition in Visual Studio" (F12) to see where it is declared.

Comment: @HenrikPettersson `string string res;` ...what? **JUST POST THE CODE**.

Comment: @HenrikPettersson - Okay, so it just looks if the string is a palindrome (thanks Andrej B.). For example "abcddcba" or "zyxyz". It does this by comparing the first character to the last, then the second character to the second to last character and so on. If there is any mismatch, `Initial` (some kind of indicator, if the string is a palindrome?) is set to false. - A string is basically an array of characters (char[]) so every character can be accessed by it's position in the string, starting with zero.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Strings in C# are actually arrays of characters.  This is why you are able to locate a single character within the string using the `[]` with an index value.

Answer (score 2):

This code set `Initial` to `false` if `ret` is not palindrome. for example:

```
var res = new int[] {1,2,3,4,5, 6}; // not palindrome
var res1 = new int[] {1,2,3,3,2, 1}; // palindrome
var resString = "notpalindrome";
var resString1 = "asdfgfdsa"; // palindrome
```

Comment: Thanks, forgot the word "palindrome". `Initial` is set to `false` if `res` is *not* a palindrome.

Answer (score 0):

Use debugger to see what's going on.

My guess it is comparing string characters (`res`, string "behaves" like array of `char`) at positions (L is length of the string) [0, L-1], [1, L-2], [2, L-3], ... and setting `Initial` to false when they are not the same.

Answer (score 0):

In c#, when you're building your classes, you can make them "indexable".
This means that you can access the underlying data by means of indexing, just like you would do with an array.

Say you have a `DuckCollection` class, which internally stores a `Duck[] duckArray` array. Now, you want users of your `DuckCollection` class to be able to do `var duck = duckCollection[0]` instead of `var duck = duckCollection.duckArray[0]`.

You'd do it like this:

```
public class DuckCollection
{
    Duck[] duckArray;

    public Duck this[int index]    // Indexer declaration
    {
        return duckArray[index];
    }


}
```

Many classes in C# implement this kind of behaviour, like strings, lists, etc. That's why you can access individual elements on strings (i.e., `char`s) as if it was an array.

More info on indexers: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2549tw02.aspx